# Display replacement characters for no-break space in Vim

Tags: vim

I'd want to display non standard spaces in Vim so that I could distinguish No-Break space (U+00A0) from Narrow No-Break space (U+202F) by using for example  replacement Unicode characters like ␣ (U+2423) and ⸤ (U+2E24) respectively.

After investigating, the best I could do was displaying the same replacement character for both no-break space types by using :

```
:set list
:set listchars=tab:▸\ ,eol:¬,trail:\ ,nbsp:␣
```

So, the listchars nbsp parameter does not differentiate standard and narrow no-break space (and it also needs the trail parameter to function proprerly, by the way).

Is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: You might be interested in the [vi.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: You can use the `conceal` feature for that.

Comment: Note that many of those characters (UTF-8 not Extended Latin) do not work unless encoding is also set to utf-8. Because of that I like to use... set listchars=tab:»·,nbsp:×,trail:«,extends:±

Answer (score 1):

You can use syntax matching and `conceal`:

```
set conceallevel=1
syn match NBSP '\%xa0' conceal cchar=␣
syn match NarrowNBSP '\%u202F' conceal cchar=⸤
```

The effext:

[image]

You could also use `set conceallevel=2`.

`conceal` replacements aren't shown in the line on which the cursor is. For, that set [`concealcursor`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27concealcursor%27):

```
set concealcursor=n
```

Comment: Hmm, sorry to ask help again, but I have a problem to get these instructions to work automatically. 
I added them in ~/.vimrc, but for every file I want to edit, I have to source .vimrc to get it to work ! 
How can I avoid that ? 
Thanks.

Comment: @hutou I cannot reproduce that. It works fine for me without having to source `.vimrc` manually. Could it be that the match groups use the same names as something else in your syntax files? Try using different names.

Comment: In fact, the problem arise only when using the etnadji/vim-epub plugin for epub editing. I'll live with that ! Thanks.